# How to get two separate cores the same IRQ signal and let them do different work

Tags: arm, interrupt, multicore, bare-metal, soc

I'm using a SOC baremetal system based on CycloneV SX with ARM based CortexA9 Dual Core HPS inside.

To ensure the synchronization of the two cores in the dual-core system, I use a 50us timer interrupt.

When the FPGA generates a 50us timer pulse, my FPGA will generate two interrupt signals, Sig1 and Sig2. Sig1 is responsible for Core0, Sig2 is responsible for Core1.

Sig1 and Sig2 are sent to the HPS GIC at the same time. If these two signals are edge-triggered and have the same priority (they should be), the GIC seems to only respond to one of them.

---

My solution is to delay one signal for a period of time, or use level-triggering. Because the frequency is very high (50us), a little delay is very fatal.

If level-triggering is used,

1. Do I need to keep the interrupt signal set during the interrupt process, and reset it after the interrupt service program ends, or just need the level signal to hold for a period of time, and let the FPGA reset itself?
2. Do you have a better solution for that? Any idea is welcome.

Comment: If there a bus like PCIe that supports message-signalled interrupts you can use?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Signaled_Interrupts .  Two separate messages should hopefully be easier to turn into two interrupts.  Or can you connect the interrupt lines to *different* IRQ numbers, and configure interrupt handling on the dual-core SoC so one core handles one, the other core handles the other?

Comment: @PeterCordes, " Or can you connect the interrupt lines to different IRQ numbers"Yes that's what I do for my project, but the result is unstable, sometimes one of signals is responeded and sometimes both are responeded. I'll check the other solution you mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: It should be possible for two independent interrupt lines to work independently!  It would be a big problem if network interrupts sometimes caused SATA controller interrupts to be lost, for example.  So it should be possible for two separate interrupt numbers to be fully independent, if you do it right.  And it should be possible to have each one always handled by a specific core.  (Maybe you can have one output from the FPGA connected to two interrupt pins on the SoC (or some config equivalent) so the same signal raises two different interrupts as far as the SoC is concerned.)

Comment: @PeterCordes My approach is to create a base frequency emitter that generates a pulse every 50us, then define another Verilog component to receive this base frequency and perform some processing, such as emitting an interrupt signal after receiving two base frequency pulses, or shifting the signal by a certain number of clock cycles.

Comment: @PeterCordes  I added two such components in the platform designer and connected them to the same base frequency emitter. Sig1 and Sig2 are sent to different IRQ channels of the GIC, both are edge-triggered, and shifted Sig2 back by one clock cycle (equivalent to shifting back by 1/100MHZ), I configured the GIC to assign Sig1 and Sig2 to Core0 and Core1 respectively. It was successful, but neither elegant nor easy to understand. Now the problem is that GICv1 seems unable to respond to simultaneous interrupt signals if they are of the same priority.  Thanks again for the information.